# Groovy asynchronous merge method with CompletableFutures not working

Tags: groovy, completable-future

I have this `SheetMerger`, which has this method for merging `SheetModel`s asynchronously. These `SheetModel`s are themselves the result of asynchronously fetching from different Sheets, some with thousands of rows, some with just a couple.

I'd like to merge, in the order of completion, the results.

Here is all the code needed to run the method `merge`:

```
public class SheetMerger {
    public SheetModel merge(List<Future<SheetModel>> promises) { 
        List<String> mergedInColumnNames = [];
        String keyColumnName;
        List<Map<String, Object>> mergedInData = [];
        
        CompletableFuture[] promisesArray = new CompletableFuture[promises.size()];
        for (int idx = 0; idx < promisesArray.size(); idx++)
            promisesArray[idx] = promises[idx];
        
        CompletableFuture.anyOf(promisesArray).get();
        
        promisesArray.eachWithIndex { CompletableFuture<SheetModel> promise, int idx ->
            println "Starting to merge Sheet number ${idx + 1}"
            
            return promise.thenAcceptAsync { SheetModel model ->
                println "Merging Sheet number ${idx + 1}"
                
                mergedInColumnNames = CollectionUtils.MergeLists(mergedInColumnNames, model.columnNames);
                
                if (keyColumnName == null)
                    keyColumnName = model.keyColumnName;
                
                mergedInData = mergeIntoDataSource(mergedInData, keyColumnName, model);
                
                println "Sheet number ${idx + 1} merged"
            }
        
        }
        
        CompletableFuture.allOf(promisesArray).get();
            
        
        return new SheetModel(mergedInColumnNames, keyColumnName, mergedInData);
    }
    
    public List<Map<String, Object>> mergeIntoDataSource(List<Map<String, Object>> masterDataSource, String masterKey, SheetModel branchModel) {  
        
        branchModel.data.eachWithIndex { Map<String, Object> branchRow, int idx ->  
            Map<String, Object> masterRow = branchRow.findResult { String key, Object value -> 
                if (!key.equals(branchModel.keyColumnName))
                    return null;
                
                return masterDataSource
                    .find { Map<String, Object> row -> return row[masterKey].equals(value) }
            }
            
            if (masterRow == null) {
                masterDataSource.push(branchRow);
                return;
            }
                
            masterDataSource[idx] = CollectionUtils.MergeMaps(masterRow, branchRow);
        }
        
        
        return masterDataSource;
    }
    
}

public final class CollectionUtils {
    /**
     * **TODO**: bring in some callback that takes masterMap, branchMap, key, and defines a merge strategy
     * @param masterMap
     * @param branchMap
     * @return
     */
    public static Map MergeMaps(Map masterMap, Map branchMap) { 
        final List<String> listOfKeys = this.MergeLists(masterMap.keySet().toList(), 
            branchMap.keySet().toList());
        
        for (String key : listOfKeys) { 
            if (!branchMap.containsKey(key))
                continue;
                
            final Object branchValue = branchMap[key]; 
            if ((branchValue == null) || (branchValue.toString().trim().equals("")))
                continue;
            
            if ((!masterMap.containsKey(key)) || (masterMap[key].toString().trim().equals("")))
                masterMap[key] = branchValue;
        }
        
        return masterMap;
    }
    
    public static List MergeLists(List masterList, List... branchLists) { 
        return masterList.plus(branchLists)
            .flatten()
            .unique()
    }
}
```

At runtime, I do not see **any** lines saying that a sheet has been merged (i.e. the actual sheet merging doesn't seem to be happening).

Here's what I see instead:

```
reading the Sheets...
merging the Sheets..
Reading Sheet 'ZohoSPOS Reconciliation' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho_spos_balance-11_42_20_01_2023_WORKING.xlsx'...
Reading Sheet 'Corrections' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v3.xlsx'...
Reading Sheet 'ZohoSPOS Reconciliation' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho_spos_balance-08_25_30_12_2022.xlERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Sheet 'Corrections' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v3.xlsx' has been parsed!
Reading Sheet 'Robert' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v1.xlsx'...
Starting to merge Sheet number 1
Starting to merge Sheet number 2
Starting to merge Sheet number 3
Starting to merge Sheet number 4
Starting to merge Sheet number 5
Sheet 'Robert' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v1.xlsx' has been parsed!
Merging Sheet number 4
Reading Sheet 'Sheet1' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v1.xlsx'...
Sheet 'Sheet1' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho-spos-balance-changes-v1.xlsx' has been parsed!
Merging Sheet number 5
Merging Sheet number 2
Sheet 'ZohoSPOS Reconciliation' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho_spos_balance-08_25_30_12_2022.xlsx' has been parsed!
Merging Sheet number 3
Sheet 'ZohoSPOS Reconciliation' in Excel file 'C:\Users\Eliza\Desktop\Upwork jobs\job\com.job.sposZohoMergeScript\excelSourceFiles\zoho_spos_balance-11_42_20_01_2023_WORKING.xlsx' has been parsed!
Merging Sheet number 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I need `synchronized` keyword. Changing my `SheetMerger` code to this fixed the issue:

```
public class SheetMerger {

    synchronized List<String> mergedInColumnNames;
    synchronized List<Map<String, Object>> mergedInData
    
    
    public SheetModel merge(List<Future<SheetModel>> promises) { 
        final SheetModel firstSheetModel = AsyncUtils.AwaitFirstResolvingPromise(promises);
        
        mergedInColumnNames = firstSheetModel.columnNames;
        mergedInData = firstSheetModel.data;
        String keyColumnName = firstSheetModel.keyColumnName;
        
        CompletableFuture<SheetModel>[] promisesArray = new CompletableFuture<SheetModel>[promises.size()];
        for (int idx = 0; idx < promisesArray.size(); idx++)
            promisesArray[idx] = promises[idx];
        
        promisesArray.eachWithIndex { CompletableFuture<SheetModel> promise, int idx ->
            println "Starting to merge Sheet number ${idx + 1}"
            
            promisesArray[idx] = promise.thenAcceptAsync { SheetModel model ->
                println "Merging Sheet number ${idx + 1}"
                
                mergedInColumnNames = CollectionUtils.MergeLists(mergedInColumnNames, model.columnNames);
                
                mergedInData = mergeIntoDataSource(mergedInData, keyColumnName, model);
                
                println "Sheet number ${idx + 1} merged"
            }
        
        }
        
        CompletableFuture.allOf(promisesArray).get();
        
        return new SheetModel(mergedInColumnNames, keyColumnName, mergedInData);
    }

    // helper method unchanged
}
```

For some odd reason, I had to manually create `CompletableFuture[]`, and write to every last array member, in the method that's using the collection, is the only way I get to use `CompletableFuture.allOf(collection).get()`... I don't understand why...

Comment: The test case is flaky tho...